# javascript iterate all items with different data types

Tags: javascript

I have an array something with like this

```
array = [
    1,
    2,
    "Paul John",
    ["PJ", 3, "Mark"],
    "Mark
]
```

The `array` variable only contains the data types above. How can I iterate through all the elements including each elements if there is another array within it?

Expectations: I should be able to fetch the values below:

```
1
2
Paul John
Pj
3
Mark
Mark
```

Comment: [MDN documentation for `Array#flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat).

Comment: use array,flat()